# ZF3 Меню категорий в шаблоне из БД

Tags: php, doctrine2, zend-framework-2

Я хочу разместить меню категорий в основном шаблоне сайта (layout), которые хранятся в БД и формируются в админке (backend), чтоб они были видны на каждой странице (frontend). Где в этом случае мне лучше всего хранить данные и как их получить в шаблоне?

Возможно ли реализовать это с помощью [Navigation](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-navigation/quick-start/) иди другое решение

Вот функция Хелпера, тут не получается сформировать ссылки категориям как в представлении $this->url(''). В данном состоянии после клика по ссылки, переходим на site/catalog/cat1, если снова нажать на ссылку, то перейдем на site/catalog/cat1/catalog/cat1:

```
public function render()
{

    $result = '';

    $categories = $this->getCategories();

    if (! is_null($categories)) {

        $categoryTree = [];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $parentId = $category->getParent() ? (int)$category->getParent()->getId() : null;
            $categoryTree[$parentId][] = $category;
        }

        foreach ($categoryTree[null] as $rootCategory) {

            $result .= '<li class="parent-li">' . $rootCategory->getName();

            if (isset($categoryTree[$rootCategory->getId()])) {
                $result .= '<ul>';
                foreach ($categoryTree[$rootCategory->getId()] as $childCategory) {
                    $result .= '<li class="child-li"><a href="'.'catalog/' . $childCategory->getUrl() . '">' . $childCategory->getName() . '</a></li>';
                }
                $result .= '</ul>';
            }
            $result .= '</li>';
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Zend Framevork 3 MVC - Doctrine 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лайаут - это вид. А значит там работают view-хелперы . Нормальным является шапку и футер делать с помощью view хелперов, а затем в лайауте делать вызов хелпера для их рендеринга. [Подробнее о добавлении хелпера](https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/zend-framework-2-create-your-custom-view-helper/).

Внутри хелпера [можно использовать navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141419/zf2-add-pages-to-navigation-in-the-controller)  - по ссылке способ добавления навигации в сервис-менеджер, а затем получение её откуда угодно, из контроллера или хелпера.

А можно не использовать - если навигация планируется не ветвистая и похожая на всех страницах, то zend-навигация покажется немного громоздкой: по моей личной практике Zend Navigation практически бесполезен даже на порталах крупнее среднего, зато сложности коду добавляет.

Comment: а без хелпера никак нельзя массив категорий в лайауте? Я не могу в Хелпере сформировать категориям ссылки в виде $this->url(...), которые работают только в представлении, как можно формировать такие ссылки в хелпере?

Comment: @Drakulitka в хелпере вы можете обращаться к виду, как `$this->view`

Comment: Все верно! Заработало, без навигации, просто $this->view->url(). Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Пошаговый туториал как делать навигацию:

https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/navigation/#setting-up-zend-navigation

Там, где у них статический массив, поменяйте на запрос из базыданных как в моём примере.

```
<?php
// in module/Application/config/module.config.php:
    return [
        /* ... */
        'navigation' => buildNavigation(),
```

**PS:** Генерировать меню динамически из Базы **очень ресурсоёмко**! Не забывайте кэшировать меню.

Comment: а где генерировать? как в примере прям в конфиге модуля? module/Application/config/module.config.php

Comment: Там где у меня в коде комментарий. Как именно вы хотите делать, зависит от проекта и стандартов кода которые приняты на проекте. Хотите пишите код прямо в функции, хотите создайте отдельный класс.

Comment: Ну вот в этом то в принципе вопрос и состоит, где их получить с помощью EntityManager из DB, где передать в представление, и как получить в представлении

Comment: Подправил ответ